# Open/Close browser after test case execution in Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How can I open and close the browser after each test case execution in Selenium?

**Scenario**: let's suppose there is a main class file, say "TestCases.JAVA", contains several test case methods and I want to open the browser at the beginning of each test case and then close browser after its execution.

Currently, I am getting the following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Tried to run command
>   without establishing a connection

The demo test cases design is like this...

```
public class TC_Login   {

    @Test(priority=1)
    public static void TC_VerifyPageTitle_1() {  
        TestBaseSetup.OpenBrowser();
        String actual=TestBaseSetup.driver.getTitle();
        String expected= "Google";

        Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);

        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Starting verify Title test");
        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Ending verify Title test");
        test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Title verified");

        TestBaseSetup.closeBrowser();
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public static void TC_Login_2() {
        TestBaseSetup.OpenBrowser();

        String actual=TestBaseSetup.driver.getTitle();
        String expected= "Google";

        Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);

        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Starting verify Title test");
        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Ending verify Title test");
        test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Title verified");
        Action.Wait(3);
        Re_Login.signIn();

        TestBaseSetup.closeBrowser();

        // test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Browser closed");
    }

}
```

I have searched on Google, but I have not found any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `BeforeMethod` and `AfterMethod` Annotations,in this example first `launchBrowser()` is called then `URLcall1()` then `closeBrowser()`, second time `launchBrowser()` is called then `URLcall2()` then `closeBrowser()`

Please find below code:

```
public class Stackoverflow_demo {

WebDriver d=null;
@BeforeMethod
public void launchBrowser()
{
 d =new FirefoxDriver();
}

@Test(priority=1)
public void URLcall1()
{
 d.get("https://google.co.in");   
}

@Test(priority=2)
public void URLcall2()
{
d.get("https://stackoverflow.com");   
}

@AfterMethod
public void closeBrowser()
{
d.close();
}     
}
```